# Chain rule with 3rd order tensors

Tags: multivariable-calculus, derivatives, matrix-calculus, tensors, chain-rule

Suppose $f : \mathbb{R}^n \to \mathbb{R}^m$ is a smooth function. I know that the Jacobian of $f$ is the linear operator $\mathbf{F} \in \mathbb{R}^{m \times n}$ such that for any (small) $\epsilon \in \mathbb{R}_+$ and $\delta \in \mathbb{R}^n$,

$$ f(x + \epsilon\delta) = f(x) + \mathbf{F} \epsilon\delta + o(\epsilon^2).$$
In other words, $f(x) + \mathbf{F}\epsilon\delta$ is an affine approximation to $f(x + \epsilon\delta)$ up to the first-order terms.

---

Now suppose that $g : \mathbb{R}^{n \times n} \to \mathbb{R}^m$ is a smooth function. Then, the derivative of $g$ will be a linear operator $\mathbf{G}$ from $\mathbb{R}^{n \times n}$ to $\mathbb{R}^m$.

1. I just know that $\mathbf{G}$ will be a "3rd order tensor" (i.e., matrix with another dimension) but I am not comfortable with using/thinking about it. This means that I should think of it as an $m \times n \times n$ object? Can you describe what $\mathbf{G}$ is exactly and how I should think of it?
2. Suppose $\delta \in \mathbb{R}^{n \times n}$. Is it correct that any such $\mathbf{G}$'s can be expressed as
   $$ \mathbf{G}(\delta) = \begin{bmatrix} \mathrm{trace}(A_1\delta) \\ \vdots \\ \mathrm{trace}(A_m\delta) \end{bmatrix}$$
   where $A_i$'s are constant (for a given $\mathbf{G}$) $n \times n$ matrices? [if so, can you please prove it?]  Is there a significance to this representation? (does $\{A_i\}$ have a name? is this representation useful for computation?)
3. How do you "multiply" such an $m \times n \times n$ object by an $n \times n$ matrix? This is needed to approximate $g(x + \epsilon\delta) \approx g(x) + \mathbf{G}(\epsilon\delta)$ where now $\delta \in \mathbb{R}^{n \times n}$.
4. Now suppose $h : \mathbb{R}^p \to \mathbb{R}^{n \times n}$. Similar to (1), what is the form of the derivative operator $\mathbf{H}$ for $h$? I can guess $\mathbf{H}(\delta) = \sum_{i} B_i \delta_i$ where $\delta \in \mathbb{R}^p$ and $B_i$'s are $n \times n$ matrices associated to $h$ - but I don't know how to prove this.
5. How do I apply the chain rule to compute the Jacobian matrix of $ g \circ h$ which is an $m \times p$ matrix? This question is related to (1) and (2). I guess the answer involve multiplying an $m \times n \times n$ tensor by and and $n \times n \times p$ tensor to get a $m \times p$ Jacobian matrix - but I don't know how to really compute this?
6. I have heard that I can vectorize the input of $g$ and the output of $h$ (such that they are mapping from/to $\mathbb{R}^{n^2}$) and then compute this with the usual chain rule based on Jacobian matrices of the stacked functions. If this is correct, can you please prove it? Is there a better way to think about and/or compute the chain rule?

Thanks for your help!

---

PS. I have seen related questions - but none was as comprehensive as this question.

Comment: Thanks @TedShifrin! (your comment is incomplete)
I understand that $g(A + \epsilon B) \approx g(A) + \epsilon\mathrm{D}(A)[B]$ where the last term (an $m$-vector) is the directional derivative (I have a similar expression in my question - written as $\mathbf{G}(\delta)$). Now if $m=1$, this term is a scalar given by $\langle G,B \rangle$ where $G$ is an $n \times n$ matrix of derivatives of $g$ evaluated at $A$. Not sure where to go from here? Pls see Qs 5 & 6. Among my other questions, I need a procedure to actually compute the m×p Jacob. of $g \circ h$ analytically for given $h$ and $g$'s.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let
$$\eqalign{
&a,b\in{\mathbb R}^{m} , \quad &x,y\in{\mathbb R}^{n}, \quad &X,Y\in{\mathbb R}^{n\times n},\quad w\in{\mathbb R}^{p} \\
&f = f(x),\quad \;\,&a = f(y),\quad &dx= x-y\\
&g = g(X),\quad \;\,&b = g(Y),\quad &dX = X-Y \\
}$$
The affine approximations are most clearly expressed using index notation (Einstein convention).
$$\eqalign{
&f_i = a_i + F_{ij}\,dx_j \\
&g_i = b_i + {\cal G}_{ijk}\,dX_{jk} \\
}$$
So $F$ is a second-order tensor and ${\cal G}$ is a third-order tensor, as you anticipated.

The approximation of a matrix-valued function is quite similar.
$$\eqalign{
X_{jk} &= Y_{jk} + {\cal H}_{jkm}\,dw_{m} \\
}$$
Substituting this into the previous formula yields an expression for the requested Jacobian.
$$\eqalign{
dX_{jk}
 &= X_{jk} - Y_{jk} \\
 &= {\cal H}_{jkm}\,dw_{m} \\
dg_i 
 &= g_i(X)-g_i(Y) \\
 &= {\cal G}_{ijk}\,dX_{jk} \\
 &= {\cal G}_{ijk}{\cal H}_{jkm}\,dw_{m} \\
\frac{\partial g_i}{\partial w_m}
 &= {\cal G}_{ijk}{\cal H}_{jkm} \\
}$$

Comment: Thanks @greg! But unfortunately this didn't add much to my understanding - pls see Qs 5 and 6. Among my other questions, I need a procedure to actually compute the $m \times p$ Jacobian of $g \circ h$ analytically for given $h$ and $g$'s.

Comment: I've updated the answer to address Q5. It is possible to flatten tensors into matrices, but it would be better if you gave us some info about the specific application that you have in mind.  It may be possible to solve your problem without involving any third-order tensors at all.